# looping over rows and copy values into an external file (sheets indexed by cell values)

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I am a newbie of VBA, so sorry for the basic question. I need to create a loop where at each iteration the script:

1. copies O6:AA6 of `Wb1` into O1:AA1 of the same Workbook
2. copies the columns B:E into `Wb2`, in the sheet named as the value contained in `N6` of `Wb1`, say "DGP1".
3. repeats the two above steps: copy O7:AA7 into O1:AA1, copy B:E into `Wb2` (sheet name given by the value contained in `N7` of `Wb1`, say "DGP2").

The code I have written, although does not implement a loop nor refers to  the values in `N6, N7`, at least performs the computations I need. After having defined the two Workbooks it consists of:

```
Wb1.Activate
    Range("O6:AA6").copy
    Range("O1:AA1").PasteSpecial
    Columns("B:E").copy
Wb2.Activate
    Sheets("DGP1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Wb1.Activate
    Range("O7:AA7").copy
    Range("O1:AA1").PasteSpecial
    Columns("B:E").copy
Wb2.Activate
    Sheets("DGP2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

In reality I have many more rows to copy-paste, and I need to refer to the final sheet names through the entries present in `N6, N7, ...`.

thanks for any suggestion,

Stefano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good start; here are some tips for writing macros that will help you get going, but also improve your code

1. **Ranges** -  Most of the time, it's faster and more efficient to set your
   "Destination" range equal to your "origin" range, if the ranges are
   the same. So, instead of doing

   ```
   Range("O6:AA6").copy
   Range("O1:AA1").PasteSpecial
   ```

   you can do...

   ```
   Range("O1:AA1") = Range("O6:AA6").Value
   ```
2. **Select** - You almost never need to "Select" cells and sheets (unless you want
   that cell/sheet to be selected when your macro has finished running).
   It's better to instead refer to the sheet directly. Again, instead
   of

   ```
   Wb1.Activate
       Range("O6:AA6").copy
       Range("O1:AA1").PasteSpecial
       Columns("B:E").copy 
   Wb2.Activate
       Sheets("DGP1").Select
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   ```

   assuming your data is on sheet 1 of `Wb1`, you can do...

   ```
   Wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O1:AA1") = Wb1.Range("O6:AA6").Value
   Wb2.Sheets("DGP1").Columns("B:E") = Wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:E").Value
   ```
3. **For Loop** - To use a `for` loop, you can set a variable and build your range
   string given an incrementing variable. For example, you can set the
   variable `x` to equal 6 and increment how ever many times you want
   (let's say 5 times to 10)

   ```
   for x = 6 to 10
       Wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O1:AA1") = _
             Wb1.Range("O" & x & ":AA" & x).Value
       Wb2.Sheets("DGP1").Columns("B:E") = _
             Wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:E").Value
   next x
   ```
4. **Range / Sheet References** - If the values in your cells are names of valid Ranges and / or sheets, they can easily be used to build a
   reference to that Range / Sheet. For example,
   `Wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N6").Value` is equal to "DPG1", the
   value in `N6` on your `Sheet1` of `Wb1`. Combining that with the
   loop, Your final code would then look like the following

   ```
       for x = 6 to 10
           Wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O1:AA1") = _
                 Wb1.Range("O" & x & ":AA" & x).Value
           Wb2.Sheets(Wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N" & x).Value).Columns("B:E") = _
                 Wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:E").Value
       next x
   ```

Now that that's done, you should know that you're going to be pasting the different values O6, O7, etc, into the same location every time (O1). I'm assuming this is not what you want, but you now have some of the tools to update that part as well.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, this covers the entire question very clearly. Regards, Stefano

Comment: Just a curiosity in terms of efficiency. As you correctly said usually it is not a good idea to activate sheets at each Excel operation. However, in my previous code (without the loop) the copy-paste operations for 10 DGPs took about 2 seconds, now almost 13. Do you think it is something related to Sheets activation? (to me the answer is "no", but as I said I don't know much about VBA..)

Comment: it could also be the fact that you're updating entire columns of data, i.e. `Wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:E").Value`. Depending on the version of excel you have, this could be a minimum of 65536 rows * 4 columns that get updated (more for excel 2007 and up), which is a lot of cells to update. It would be better to select a finite area of cells, say `Wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:E5000").Value`

Answer (score 1):

Try this (you need to rename the Workbook names and Worksheet names):

```
Sub SO_19646599()
    Dim oWB1 As Workbook, oWB2 As Workbook
    Dim oWS1 As Worksheet, oWS2 As Worksheet
    Dim oRngRef As Range, oRng1 As Range, oRng2 As Range
    Dim sTmp As String, iOffset As Long, iErr As Long, sErr As String

    ' Source Workbook and Worksheet (assumed already open)
    Set oWB1 = Workbooks("Wb1")
    Set oWS1 = oWB1.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Assuming Sheet1
    ' Target Workbook (assumed already open)
    Set oWB2 = Workbooks("Wb2")
    ' Reference range to start
    Set oRngRef = oWS1.Range("N6")
    ' Offset counter
    iOffset = 0
    ' Loop until oRngRef is an empty cell
    Do Until IsEmpty(oRngRef)
        ' Copy O6:AA6 to O1:AA1 in Wb1 (assuming Sheet1), with row offset
        Set oRng1 = oWS1.Range("O6:AA6").Offset(iOffset, 0)
        Set oRng2 = oWS1.Range("O1:AA1").Offset(iOffset, 0)
        oRng1.Copy Destination:=oRng2
        ' Get reference to Worksheet in Wb2 by the value contained in N6 of Wb1 (assumed Sheet1), with row offset
        sTmp = oRngRef.Value
        Set oWS2 = oWB2.Worksheets(sTmp)
        If oWS2 Is Nothing Then
            iErr = iErr + 1
            sErr = sErr & iErr & vbTab & "No such """ & sTmp & """ worksheet (" & oRngRef.Address & ") in " & oWB2.Name & vbCrLf
        Else
            ' copies the columns B:E from Wb1 (Sheet1) to Wb2 (Sheet name as N6)
            oWS1.Columns("B:E").Copy Destination:=oWS2.Columns("B:E")
        End If
        iOffset = iOffset + 1
        ' Update Reference range
        Set oRngRef = oWS1.Range("N6").Offset(iOffset, 0)
    Loop
    If iErr > 0 Then
        Debug.Print sErr
        MsgBox iErr & " errors occurred, please review Immediate window." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & sErr
    End If
    ' Cleanup
    Set oWS2 = Nothing
    Set oWB2 = Nothing
    Set oWS1 = Nothing
    Set oWB1 = Nothing
End Sub
```